# Python: Trouble with inheritance and super call

Tags: python, inheritance, super

I am trying to learn python (with little prior programming experience) and got stuck on this problem on codeacademy about calling methods from a base class after overwriting it in a subclass.

This is the code:

```
class Employee(object):
    """Models real-life employees!"""
    def __init__(self, employee_name):
        self.employee_name = employee_name

    def calculate_wage(self, hours):
        self.hours = hours
        return hours * 20.00


 class PartTimeEmployee(Employee):
    def calculate_wage(self, hours):
        self.hours = hours
        return hours * 12.00

    def full_time_wage(self, hours):
         super(PartTimeEmployee, self).calculate_wage(self, hours)

milton = PartTimeEmployee("Milton")
print(milton.full_time_wage(10))
```

Unfortunately it throws the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 20, in <module>
  File "python", line 17, in full_time_wage
TypeError: calculate_wage() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

So somewhere one variable too many is handed over, however, I cannot figure out where.

**Update 1:**

Resolved the Traceback call by passing only hours on line 17.

However, now my result for calling 
    `print(milton.full_time_wage(10))`
gives me `None`instead of 200 as I would expect.
Can someone maybe enlighten me as to what I a mdoing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Thank you, that took care of the error message. However, for some reason this will - for the call above 'print(milton.full_time_wage(10))' - return 'None' instead of '20'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to call calculate_wage() with self as one of the parameters:

should be:

```
class PartTimeEmployee(Employee):
    def calculate_wage(self, hours):
       self.hours = hours
       return hours * 12.00

    def full_time_wage(self, hours):
        super(PartTimeEmployee, self).calculate_wage(hours)
```

Comment: Thank you, that took care of the error message. However, for some reason this will - for the call above 'print(milton.full_time_wage(10))' - return 'None' instead of '20'.

Comment: @more_dread do you have a `return` statement? No you don't...every function without a `return` statement returns `None`

Answer (score 1):

The line needs to be:

```
return super(PartTimeEmployee, self).calculate_wage(hours)
```

The method call already passes self. You have to return the result of calling the method.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is the second `self` that you're passing to the function.

```
super(PartTimeEmployee, self).calculate_wage(self, hours)
                                              ^
```

When you pass the `self` to the `super` it will automatically pass the super class to the function (if it provides that function). Otherwise it will look for the the function in other bases in your classes `__mro__`.

Read more in documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#super

Answer (score 0):

So, the error message was resolved by all answers above.

And the problem with my code returning nothing is that I forgot the `return`call on line 17 - I am an idiot..